# DIV Active state - Style change

Tags: javascript, html

I have created 04 buttons and defined the active states for each button in the CSS. These active states are called in JS, so that it changes the div style property on clicked and then resets the property when the other button is clicked.

But this is not working for me.

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aki_shaitan/AAM7L/)`DIV TAG` for this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code from being called `onLoad` to be called `No wrap - in <head>`.

Because the functions were inside the onLoad function scope and not the global scope, they were not readable and no javascript was being called when clicking the buttons.

I didn't change any code, just the option on the left pane:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AAM7L/2/)

## Update

You also had a small flaw in logic causing the classes to become intertwined. Here's what you were doing:

> When first object is clicked, set it's class to obj1_active. When second object is clicked set obj1's class to obj2 and set obj2's class to obj2_active.

As you  can see, we're crossing obj1 and obj2 classes. To solve this, we'll keep track of the last object clicked (`role`) and the class that it should be when a new object is clicked (`cname`).

Here is the Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AAM7L/9/)

### Optimization

The code you have works, but it's not very optimized. We shouldn't need four different functions that all do essentially the same thing just to different elements.

In this demo, I simply add and remove `_active` from the className of each element when clicked: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AAM7L/13/)

**Lets take it a step further** and use multiple classes. This is useful to be able to generalize our CSS declarations. Lets use the default classes, and only append the `active` class onto the active element and remove it when a new element is clicked.

We'll also separate the `_` in the classNames so that `btn` is its own class as well as `mission`. This allows for us to really clean up our CSS code to improve readability as well as not need to update multiple sections when we just need a simple background color update or something of that nature.

Here is the optimized demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AAM7L/11/)

#### Link Color

I'm not sure if you meant to do this, but you'll notice that the links sometimes start white then turn to black when clicked. This is because the `:link` pseudo selector only selects non-visited links. If you want it to select all links, then just use the `<a>` tag: [Final jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AAM7L/12/)

Comment: Still this is not solving the issue. The active colors for each buttons are different, and after one click its not using the correct DIV Active states.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice this behavior. I added a whole section describing how to fix this as well as further optimization of your code. Hope you find it helpful!

Comment: Thank you so much. You solved my problem as well as explained the possible way to improve the codes. Excellent :)

Comment: The JS is not working properly with the IE8. Can you help me to fix this.

Comment: Can you explain what's happening? It seems to work in IE7+ on my computer. jsFiddle usually doesn't work for me in any IE browser less than 9. I append `show` to the URL to view it in IE as in here: http://jsfiddle.net/AAM7L/14/show/

Comment: Whenever I click on the buttons for the first time, this works fine ( I mean the button states). And after that this disappeared. This probmlem only occured in IE8 nd below. It's hard to explain in jsfiddle. May be I need to chngle the HTML doctype? Any suggestion from you?

Comment: Hi @Evan kindly help me with my query